# Sumif formula with source from variable name and fill down the cells

Tags: vba, excel, variables, sumifs

I looked around on the forum, but could not find enough information to succeed. Appreciate your help throughout the process.

The top portion seems to work, but when I get to `range.formula` section, it doesn't work. I'm trying to reference to a sheet with variable name, then fill down the formula. To make sure formula goes all the way to the bottom, I refer it to column C as it will always have data without blanks.

```
Sub SubName()
    If (Worksheets("Master Data").AutoFilterMode And _
      Worksheets("Master Data").FilterMode) Or _
      Worksheets("Master Data").FilterMode Then
        Worksheets("Master Data").ShowAllData
    End If
    Dim curDate As String, Fname As String
    curDate = Format(Date, "yyyy-mm-dd")
    Dim wba As Workbook
    Fname = "Y:\Consumables\Company\ABC\DMC - Planning & Materials\On Hand Reports\ABC Site\" & _
      curDate & "_INV_R12_ABC_Onhandreport.xlsx"
    Set wba = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=Fname, UpdateLinks:=False, Notify:=False)
    Dim wb As Workbook

    For Each wb In Application.Workbooks
        If wb.Name Like "*PFEP*" Then wb.Activate
    Next wb
    Sheets("Master Data").Select
    Range("AL8:AL" & Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row).Formula = _
      "=SUMIF('[" &_INV_R12_ABC_Onhandreport.xlsx & "]Sheet'!C2,RC[-35],'[" & INV_R12_ABC_Onhandreport.xlsx & "]Sheet'!C17)"
End Sub
```

Comment: I searched, but still cannot figure out where the Sumif formula is incorrect. Please help. I'm stumped.

Comment: When relevant, always include `excel`, `excel-vba` and `vba` tags, because they are followed a lot. Therefore, a lot more people will see your question.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see, you have too many quote symbols. Try this:

```
Range("AL8:AL" & Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row).Formula = _ 
  "=SUMIF('[_INV_R12_ABC_Onhandreport.xlsx]Sheet'!C2,RC[-35],'[INV_R12_ABC_Onhandreport.xlsx]Sheet'!C17)"
```

Let me know if it helps.